# Comparing linear regression models created from different data sets

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I have one linear regression model [Mold] created from 12 points where I can calculate a single value of RMSE between the predicted values and the actual observed values. This model is then used to predict another dataset [Box, 42 points].

I have a second linear regression model [Box] in which all combinations of 12 points out of a 42 point sample are selected and RMSE between the predicted values and actual observed values is calculated for all combinations. The linear regression model in this scenario predicts the other 30 points not selected to construct the regression model.

I am trying to figure out a way to compare the [Mold model] and the [Box model] with a statistical technique.

My idea at the moment is to compare the single RMSE value from the [Mold Model] to a CDF of the RMSE from the multiple combinations of [Box Model]. Therefore I could say **XX%** of the time, the [Box Model] has an RMSE of **XX** better/worse than the [Mold Model].

If someone can please comment on the best technique you think I should be using it would be greatly appreciated. My master's thesis depends on it! Thanks!